# Format statements in Fortran modules

Tags: module, fortran, fortran90, fortran95, formats

I have a module with a number of subroutines that all use the same set of formats for output.
Right now, I have to declare the formats in every subroutine.  Is there a way to declare them in the module so all the subroutines have access to them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the format as a character at the module level. E.g.

```
module foo
  implicit none
  character(len=20), parameter :: form = "(1X,A)"
contains
subroutine bar
  ...
   write(my_unit, form) "Hello, World"
end subroutine bar
end module foo
```